# This program is supposed to draw a house. But the functions won't work

Tags: c, cygwin

I'm trying to write this program in C to draw a house out of either stars, dashes, or dots. It asks the user a set of questions (big or small house), (what characters to use?), (how many windows?) and then it's supposed to draw the house. I didn't add any code for invalid responses yet because I want to check if it works with valid responses first, but it doesn't. After the third question, Cygwin says "Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)". Can someone please tell me what the problem is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define house 1

char qbs; // for quit big small
char dsd; // for dash star dot
int now; // number of windows
int i, f; // random variables for for loops


main()
{
while(house) {
printf("Do you want a big or small house? (Q: quit, B: big house, S: small house)\n");
scanf("%s", &qbs);
switch(qbs){
    case 'B': 
    case 'b': 
    case 's':
    case 'S': break;
    default : printf("%s is not a valid choice. Please try again.\n", qbs);
              continue;
    }

printf("Which characters do you want for drawing? (DASH(-), STAR(*), or DOT(.))\n");
scanf("%s", &dsd);
printf("Using %c to draw the house.\n", dsd);

printf("How many windows do you want in the house? (0 through 4 for big houses and 0 through 2 for small houses.)\n");
scanf("%d", &now);

switch(dsd){
        case '-': dsd='-';
                  break;

        case '*': dsd='*';
                  break;

        case '.': dsd='.';
                  break;
        }
printf("%c %c %d", qbs, dsd, now);

switch(qbs){
        case 'Q':
        case 'q': printf("QUITTING THE PROGRAM.\n"); break;

        case 'B':
        case 'b': printf("         "); // this line and the next 7 lines draw the BIG roof 
                  for(i=0; i<=42; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);}
                  printf("\n      ");
                  for(i=0; i<=48; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);}
                  printf("\n   ");
                  for(i=0; i<=56; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);}
                  printf("\n");
                  for(i=0; i<=62; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);}
                 switch(now) { 
                    case '0':
                        for(f=0; i<=15; f++) { // the vertical expansion
                            for(i=0; i<=62; i++) {printf("%s", dsd); printf("\n");} // the horizontal expansion
                        }
                        break;

                    case '1':
                        for(i=0; i<=62; i++) {printf("%s", dsd); printf("\n");} // first line with no windows
                        for(f=0; f<=13; f++) { 
                            for(i=0; i<=28; i++) { printf("%s", dsd); } // left side of window
                            for(i=0; i<=6; i++) { printf(" "); } // window
                            for(i=0; i<=28; i++) { printf("%s"); } // right side of window
                        }
                        for(f=0; f<=2; f++) { for(i=0; i<=62; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);}} // bottom two lines with no windows
                        break;

                    case '2': 
                        for(i=0; i<=62; i++) {printf("%s", dsd); printf("\n");} // first line with no windows
                        for(f=0; f<=13; f++) {
                            for(i=0; i<=21; i++) { printf("%s", dsd); } // left side
                            for(i=0; i<=7; i++) {printf(" ");} // first window
                            for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);} // space between windows
                            for(i=0; i<=7; i++) {printf(" ");} // second window
                            for(i=0; i<=21; i++) { printf("%s", dsd); } // right side
                        }
                        for(f=0; f<=2; f++) { for(i=0; i<=62; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);}} // bottom two lines with no windows
                        break;

                    case '3': 
                        for(i=0; i<=62; i++) {printf("%s", dsd); printf("\n");} // first line with no windows
                        for(f=0; f<=13; f++) {
                            for(i=0; i<=11; i++) { printf("%s", dsd);} // left side
                            for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {printf(" "); } // first window
                            for(i=0; i<=11; i++) { printf("%s", dsd);} // space between window 1 and 2
                            for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {printf(" "); } // second window
                            for(i=0; i<=11; i++) { printf("%s", dsd);} // space between window 2 and 3
                            for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {printf(" "); } // third window
                            for(i=0; i<=11; i++) { printf("%s", dsd);} // right side
                        }
                        for(f=0; f<=2; f++) { for(i=0; i<=62; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);}} // bottom two lines with no windows
                        break;

                    case '4': 
                        for(i=0; i<=62; i++) {printf("%s", dsd); printf("\n");} // first line with no windows
                        for(f=0; f<=13; f++) {
                            for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);} // left side
                            for(i=0; i<=8; i++) {printf(" ");} // first window
                            for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);} // space between win1 and win2
                            for(i=0; i<=8; i++) {printf(" ");} // second window
                            for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);} // space between win2 and win3
                            for(i=0; i<=8; i++) {printf(" ");} // third window
                            for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);} // space between win3 and win4
                            for(i=0; i<=8; i++) {printf(" ");} // fourth window
                            for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);} // right side
                        }
                        for(f=0; f<=2; f++) { for(i=0; i<=62; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);}} // bottom two lines with no windows


        case 'S':
        case 's': printf("         "); // this line and the next 7 lines draw the SMALL roof
                  for(i=0; i<=12; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);}
                  printf("\n      ");
                  for(i=0; i<=18; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);}
                  printf("\n   ");
                  for(i=0; i<=24; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);}
                  printf("\n");
                  for(i=0; i<=30; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);}
                  switch(now) { 
                    case '0':
                        for(f=0; i<=6; f++) { // the vertical expansion
                        for(i=0; i<=30; i++) {printf("%s", dsd); printf("\n");} // the horizontal expansion
                        }
                        break;

                    case '1':
                        for(f=0; f<=5; f++) { 
                        for(i=0; i<=12; i++) { printf("%s", dsd); } // left side of window
                        for(i=0; i<=6; i++) { printf(" "); } // window
                        for(i=0; i<=12; i++) { printf("%s"); } // right side of window
                        }
                    for(f=0; f<=1; f++) { for(i=0; i<=30; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);}} // bottom line with no windows
                    break;

                    case '2': 
                        for(f=0; f<=5; f++) {
                            for(i=0; i<=6; i++) { printf("%s", dsd); } // left side
                            for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {printf(" ");} // first window
                            for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);} // space between windows
                            for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {printf(" ");} // second window
                            for(i=0; i<=6; i++) { printf("%s", dsd); } // right side
                        }
                    for(f=0; f<=1; f++) { for(i=0; i<=62; i++) {printf("%s", dsd);}} // bottom line with no windows
                    break;
                  printf("Small house with %d windows\n", now);
                  break;
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Pretty confusing code. However, did you try to use a debugger?

Comment: I used cygwin as a terminal and gcc as a compiler to check for errors, if that's what you mean :/ It compiles fine so there are no errors

Comment: Programs that require input are hard to debug. Construct a minimal example, preferably without a menu. For example, start by drawing a house and see if you still get a segmentation fault.

Comment: There are several obvious mistakes in this code, you need to reduce it to a [minimal example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "it compiles fine so there are no errors" is one of my all time favourite programming phrases.

Comment: `There are no errors`. If there were no errors, your program would not seg fault.

Answer (score 1):

In your whole code, try to replace

```
printf("%s", dsd)
```

by

```
printf("%c", dsd)
```

And do the same for your scanf. You want characters, not strings.

Anyway that's funny, a day ago someone wanted to draw the same house, is this an exercice for your studies ? ^^

Comment: Not in his last switch but everywhere! the OP has mixed up %s with %c :)